# Empty numeric in dbf created by dbfpy

Tags: python, dbf

I have .dbf file with numeric column. I want to cells in a numeric column were empty. I try this code:

```
db = dbf.Dbf("temp.dbf", new=True)
db.addField(('ACCT_ID', 'C',10),
("NUMROW","N",9),

for acct_id  in data:
     rec = db.newRecord()
     rec["ACCT_ID"] = a[nse]["ACCT_ID"]
     rec.store()
db.close()
```

But then i read data from file i have ***0*** in **NUMROW**. Also i try change dbfpy to dbf, byt i have same result. Can anyone help me? is it possible to create empty cell in numeric column?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a field capable of holding Null.  To do that with [dbf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) you will need to create the table with a type that supports Null fields, such as FoxPro:

```
# not tested
db = dbf.Table('temp', 'acct_id C(10) null; numrow N(9,0', dbf_type='vfp')
db.open()
for acct_id in data:
    db.append(dict(acct_id=acct_id, numrow=None))
db.close()
```

Now, when you go back and read the field you should get a value for `acct_id` and `None` for `numrow`.